# How to pass props to component both with mapDispatchToProps and from parent component?

Tags: reactjs

I have a parent component from which I want to pass down to the child component action from redux and some static props

When I'm doing it like that my child component receiving action, and some default props like history but `func` doesn't get passed down

Is there a way to pass down both props from store and just from parent component?

```
export const Parent = () => {
  const onFunc= e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(34234234);
  };
  return (
    <Child
      func={onFunc}
    />
  );
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  storeAction: data => dispatch(storeAction(data))
});

export default connect(
  null,
  mapDispatchToProps,
)(Child);
```

Comment: Where do you call onFunc? Also looks like you never passed down props.storeAction

Comment: Or don't make your code have that kind of dependency. When you connect the component with `react-redux`.. `dispatch` is extended as a prop. Instead of passing function references around and setting up more dependency, just connect the component that needs to do the dispatching and dispatch from there. You essentially don't really need `mapDispatchToProps`

Comment: @ChristopherNgo I call onFunc in Child component. And when I `console.log` props storeAction is there, in Child component

Comment: Allan, see my answer. That is because you are calling `connect` on the `Child` component not the `Parent` component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are exporting a connect on the child not the parent. So the parent never renders. You can just connect the parent instead

```
export default connect(
  null,
  mapDispatchToProps,
)(Parent);
```